# PhoneGap 2.8.0 raising "no method 'overrideBackbutton'" with angular-mobile-nav

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am having an issue with angular-mobile-nav on the very initial page load of Cordova 2.8 Android project using Ripple Emulator.  The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'overrideBackbutton'
    at module.exports.exec (chrome-extension://geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/ripple.js:40:22917)
    at backButtonChannel.onHasSubscribersChange (http://localhost:8076/cordova.js:1145:13)
    at Channel.subscribe (http://localhost:8076/cordova.js:667:49)
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (http://localhost:8076/cordova.js:132:34)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8076/components/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js:11:14)
    at Channel.fire (http://localhost:8076/cordova.js:709:23)
    at http://localhost:8076/cordova.js:232:47
```

Basically, it is cause by mobile-nav.js line 11:
`document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {`

And error raised by cordova.js' call originating from line 1145:
`exec(null, null, "App", "overrideBackbutton", [this.numHandlers == 1]);`

Is this a problem that you can replicate?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I first encountered this when using Ripple with Phonegap 2.5.0. As you point out, on line 1145 of cordova-2.8.0.js for Android, it assumes to be running on the Android platform so calls the native function App.overrideBackbutton() which Ripple doesn't have a stub for.

Since it only calls this on attaching/detaching the first handler, I worked around this by tricking Ripple into thinking there's already more than one handler:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        _IS_RIPPLE_EMULATOR = $('#tinyhippos-injected').length > 0;

        function deviceready() {
            // Make ripple think that a back button handler has already been attached
            if(_IS_RIPPLE_EMULATOR) cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('backbutton'); 

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
                alert("Pressed back");
            });

        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I discovered it out of necessity ;-)

Comment: I found that the 
cordova.addDocumentEventHandler('backbutton');
command absolutely must be placed in the deviceready() function or it will not work

Comment: I use phonegap 3.30 and the new (non-plugin) revision of Rippple, the detection method in this answer did not work for me but something very similar works ````var _IS_RIPPLE_EMULATOR = (window.tinyHippos != undefined);````

Answer (score 1):

As of Ripple 0.9.22 this should no longer be an issue since **App.exitApp** and **App.overrideBackbutton** methods were added:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-ripple.git;a=log;h=refs/tags/0.9.22

So, if possible update your version of Ripple, or resort to the workaround mentioned by Dpa99c.